# ajax retorna html completo codeigniter 3

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

Estoy tratando de hacer un simple ajax con codeigniter, pero en el success, me está devolviendo todo el HTML de mi página.

estas son mis rutas:

```
// Usuarios
$route["usuarios"] = "usuario/index";
$route["usuarios/(.*)"] = "usuario/$1";
```

en la ruta `$route["usuarios/(.*)"]` tengo un método en mi controller que se llama desimpersonar() que lo que hace es borrar la sesión actual y establecer la anterior.

y en mi vista tengo:

```
let data = {
            id: $(".desinpersonar").attr("data-id")
        };

        $(".desinpersonar").on('click', function(){
                bootbox.confirm({
                buttons: {
                    confirm: {
                        label: 'Aceptar',
                        className: 'btn-success pull-left'
                    },
                    cancel: {
                        label: 'Cancelar',
                        className: 'btn-danger'
                    }
                },
                title: "Dejar de suplantar",
                message: msg,
                callback: function(e){
                    $.ajax({
                        url: base_url() + "usuarios/desimpersonar",
                        method: "POST",
                        data: data,
                        contentType: false,
                        processData: false,//this is a must
                        success: function(response){
                            console.log("aqui: "+response)
                            //document.location = base_url();
                        },
                        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                            console.log("entro en error")
                            //error_redirect(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        });
```

Me está entrando en el success response, pero en mi controller solo tengo para que me muestre un mensaje:

```
public function desimpersonar(){
        return "llego al controller";
        /*if ($this->session->userdata("tipo_usuario") == "ADM1") {
            $user = $this->Usuario_model->ObtenerUsuario($this->input->post("id"));

            $suplantador = ($this->session->has_userdata("login_alias")) ? $this->session->userdata("login_alias") : $this->session->userdata("identity");

            // Guardar los datos del usuario suplantado
            $session_data = array(
                'identity'         => $user->LOGIN,
                'login'            => $user->LOGIN,
                'email'            => $user->EMAIL,
                'user_id'          => $user->ID, //everyone likes to overwrite id so we'll use user_id
                'old_last_login'   => $user->FECHA_ULTIMA_CONEXION,
                'nombre_comercial' => $user->NOMBRE_COMERCIAL,
                'descripcion'      => $user->DESCRIPCION,
                'tipo_usuario'     => $user->TIPO_USUARIO,
                'id_padre'         => $user->ID_PADRE,
                'permisos'         => $user->PERMISOS,
                'padres'           => $user->PADRES,
                'ip'               => $user->IP_ULTIMA_CONEXION,
                'noticias'         => $user->NOTICIAS,
                'login_suplantador'=> $suplantador,
                'impersonar'       => true
            );

            $this->session->unset_userdata($session_data);
        }*/
    }
```

Pero la respuesta de mi ajax, es todo el HTML de la página... He probado a poner dataType: 'json', dataType: false, etc. Pero siempre me devuelve error, o bien el html o el error del ajax.

Agradezco toda ayuda para saber que me está pasando.

Un saludo

Comment: ¿Y si en lugar de un return haces un echo y luego le pones un die() para que no se le ocurra continuar por otro lado?

Comment: @masterguru mismo resultado... aparece el html

Comment: Que HTML te muestra? Ya que no veo algun tag de HTML, tal vez sea una página de error y eso te regresa

Comment: Puede ser que estés teniendo un error de CORS

Comment: @FernandoTorres y masterguru ya está solucionado. No estaba haciendo bien la funcion de php